# Flutter - how to do i forward mapped data to another page

Tags: flutter, object, dart

I have three files - companies.dart, Company_Card_Style.dart and Company_Details.
I'm mapping company parameters to company_card_Style from companies.dart, now i need to send the same data to companyDetails.dart, what should i pass in MaterialPageroute and how to receive in companyDetails

1. Companies file - in itembuilder, im passing a company detail to companycardstyle

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Object.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'UI_Styles/Company_Card_Style.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Companies extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CompaniesState createState() => _CompaniesState();
}

class _CompaniesState extends State<Companies> {
  Future<List<Company>> _getCompanies() async {
    var data = await http.get("http://localhost/crm_demo/getData.php");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<Company> companies = [];
    for (var c in jsonData) {
      Company company = Company(
          c["name"],
          c["address"],
          c["opportunities"],
          c["pipelineRevenue"],
          c["revenueAchieved"],
          c["city"],
          c["state"],
          c["country"],
          c["zipcode"],
          c["phone"],
          c["timezone"],
          c["tags"]);
      companies.add(company);
    }
    return companies;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
          "Companies",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        )),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getCompanies(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return CompanyCardStyle(company: snapshot.data[index]);
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

CompanyCardStyle.dart - Here on click of company name i want to redirect to detail page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Object.dart';
import '../Detail_Pages/Company_details.dart';

class CompanyCardStyle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Company company;
  CompanyCardStyle({this.company});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          tilePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          leading: CircleAvatar(radius: 20.0, child: Text(company.name[0])),
          subtitle: Flexible(
              child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => CompanyDetails(company: company)),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              company.address,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          )),
          title:
              Text(company.name, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      companyLabels('Phone Number'),
                      companyLabels('Opportunities'),
                      companyLabels('Pipeline Revenue'),
                      companyLabels('Revenue Achieved'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        companyValues(company.phone.toString()),
                        companyValues(company.opportunities),
                        companyValues(company.pipelineRevenue.toString()),
                        companyValues(company.revenueAchieved.toString())
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ]))
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget companyLabels(String values) {...}

  Widget companyValues(String values) {...}
}
```

CompanyDetails.dart - Let me know how should i get data here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CompanyDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CompanyDetailsState createState() => _CompanyDetailsState();
}

class _CompanyDetailsState extends State<CompanyDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("I have to display rest of the company data here"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an issue with your endpoint, not with flutter/dart.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this on CompanyDetails.dart

```
class CompanyDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  CompanyDetails ({Key key, this.company})
      : super(key: key);

  final Company company;

@override
  _CompanyDetailsState createState() => _CompanyDetailsState();
}


class _CompanyDetailsState extends State<CompanyDetails> {
  Company company;

  @override
  void initState() {
    company= widget.company;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("My company name is ${company.name}"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error, ```lib/UI_Styles/Company_Card_Style.dart:22:67: Error: The argument type 'BuildContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Company'.``` Also i think we are not passing the same company details, in this method we are simple importing company object.

Comment: that approach did not work, now i have all my code in companies.dart file (the code from companyCardStyle.dart), and send the data to companyDetails.page. working fine but not clean approach.